# Delete all content from WordPress posts default editor in bulk

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've made a website using ACF and all the content has been copied over from the default WordPress editor, to the new ACF fields.

The trouble is my client didn't delete the content from the default WordPress editor as they went along. Subsequently, it's causing loads of broken links.

Long story short, is there a way to delete all content from the default post editor site wide, rather than update every single post?

Answer (score 0):

To Delete all content from Wordpress posts you will need to export all posts ID in a CSV file.

In PhpMyAdmin you could use

```
SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts`
```

Then export the query result in a CSV file. Open the CSV and create a new column for the content which you want empty.

To test my answer, I installed the free version of the 1st WordPress plugin I found for the search query `csv import` on https://wordpress.org/plugins/

Then on your WordPress dashboard go to this newly installed plugin menu and import the CSV file previously created.

Let the importer **update** existing posts and define the **content** as the only column to update.

Before updating All content, I would make a test of the importer configuration on 1 unpublished test post to make sure ACF field aren't emptied with the import.

Which may not happen if you don't miss a configuration on the importer.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL this is a straight task for deleting all content from the default post, i.e using PHPMyAdmin, SQL section after selecting WP database (i.e find name in wp-config.php):

```
DELETE * FROM wp_posts
DELETE * FROM wp_postmeta
```

**Please note** this will remove ***definitively*** ALL content from your website, always take a backup.

You can also find a manual plugin for doing this [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48214/manually-delete-post-from-database).

Comment: This would also delete ACF fields and any other content in the WordPress! Definitely not the solution @Charly is looking for!

Comment: QUestion was: "is there a way to delete all content from the default post editor site wide, rather than update every single post"

It seems clear, don't you? :-)

Comment: For me it's clear @Charly wants to delete the content inside the posts and more precisely the one inside the default content "box" in WordPress Dashboard. It's said content as been moved in ACF Fields and for what I understand it is in the same post so if you delete the post you will also lose ACF Fields contents.

Comment: @gael you're correct, I was looking to retain the content in ACF and only delete content within the default Wordpress editor. I opted for doing it manually as I didn't want to risk loosing everything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yep @CharlyAnderson it's sometimes quicker to make changes manually than to make a full process for only 1 import. My solution below can still be usefull for someone facing the same problem with hundreds of posts for example.